# Change form to multi image image instead of single image PHP

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

My website currently lets me upload 1 photo at a time for each of my listed vehicles. This process takes some time, and it would be convenient to be able to drop all photos into 1 field and have them upload properly. Any help is great!

[image: Backend of the image upload]

```
<?php  
if(isset($slider_image)){ 
    if(!empty($slider_image)){ 
        foreach($slider_image as $s){ 
?>
           <div class="col-md-4 hide_me_<?php echo $s->id; ?>" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
               <a href="<?php echo site_url('uploads/'.$s->image); ?>" class="lightbox">
                    <img src="<?php echo site_url('uploads/'.$s->image); ?>" alt="<?php echo $s->title; ?>" class="img-media ">
                </a> 
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="remove_me(<?php echo $s->id; ?>)"  class="btn btn-danger my_btn" style="margin-top:0px; margin-left:10px;">Remove Image</a>
           </div>
<?php 
        } 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please dont Squish code up together like that. Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Add `multiple` to the `<input type="file" ...... multiple>`

Comment: There are JS plugins like Dropzone out there and the PHP manual has a page on [Uploading multiple files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)